# jquery not firing for link added using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of images that are also link such as follows:

```
<a href="#"><img alt="P1010104" class="uploaded_image" src="/assets/user_images/156/thumb/P1010104.jpg?1335332807" /></a>

<a href="#"><img alt="P1010104" class="uploaded_image" src="/assets/user_images/157/thumb/P1010105.jpg?1335332809" /></a>
```

I have some javascript that adds the images to a page when one image is clicked:

```
//add an image from the gallery to the mail later
  $('.uploaded_image').click(function(){
      alert('clicked');
      var src=$(this).attr('src').replace("thumb", "medium");
      var location = $('#user_image_location').attr('value');
      $('#mailing_body').contents().find("[data-edit-img="+''+location+''+"]").attr('src', src);
      $('[data-dismiss]="cancel"').click();
});
```

I user some ajax to add another image to the images list. However when I click on this newly added image the javascript does not fire.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [jquery `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.uploaded_image', function(){
      alert('clicked');
      var src=$(this).attr('src').replace("thumb", "medium");
      var location = $('#user_image_location').attr('value');
      $('#mailing_body').contents().find("[data-edit-img="+''+location+''+"]").attr('src', src);
      $('[data-dismiss]="cancel"').click();
});
```

jquery 1.7+

Comment: Thanks for all the answers it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.on()`

```
$('.uploaded_image').on('click', function(){
      alert('clicked');
      var src=$(this).attr('src').replace("thumb", "medium");
      var location = $('#user_image_location').attr('value');
      $('#mailing_body').contents().find("[data-edit-img="+''+location+''+"]").attr('src', src);
      $('[data-dismiss]="cancel"').click();
});
```

**.click()** will not work because your elements are not in the DOM when the .click handler is registered.

If you are using jQuery Versions below 1.7 you will have to use `.bind()` instead of `.on()`

**Documentation:**

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 0):

Jquery normally wouldn't support dynamically loaded content.

Earlier you had to use .live() . Now  it has been deprecated and  you are supposed to use **.on()** Handler.

Syntax:

```
.on( events [, selector] [, data] , handler(eventObject) ) ;
```

Your code ( adapted . Not tested ) :

```
$('.uploaded_image').on("click", function(){
      alert('clicked');
      var src=$(this).attr('src').replace("thumb", "medium");
      var location = $('#user_image_location').attr('value');
      $('#mailing_body').contents().find("[data-edit-img="+''+location+''+"]").attr('src', src);
      $('[data-dismiss]="cancel"').click();
});
```

[Refer Jquery API for more details about .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)